# How do I query select by order my highscores for my scoreboard

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I wish to be able to display the scores on textmeshpros (in order of highest to lowest) that are written in my firebase collection named Score:

Firebase tree:
[image]

EDIT: I have since modified my code to look like this to make things simpler.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Firebase.Firestore;
using Firebase.Extensions;
using TMPro;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI _points;
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI _nbIles;

    FirebaseFirestore db;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        db = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance;
        EcrireFirestore();
    }

    void EcrireFirestore(){

        CollectionReference scoreRef = db.Collection("Score");
        Dictionary<string,object> scoreAMettre = new Dictionary<string,object>{
            {"Nom:", Mort.nomJoueur},
            { "Points", BiomesEtatCultiver.pointFleur},
            { "Nombre d'iles completer", Sacrifice.nbIleFait},
        };
        scoreRef.AddAsync(scoreAMettre);

        // CollectionReference scoreRefCol = db.Collection("Score");
        Query query = scoreRef.OrderByDescending("Points").Limit(5);
        query.GetSnapshotAsync();
        Debug.Log(query.GetSnapshotAsync());

        // // _points.text = ""+query.GetSnapshotAsync();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, Are you asking about Paginate the query ? if so the related doc is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query) And have you verified getting the value from `query.GetSnapshotAsync()` like this ? : `QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.GetSnapshotAsync();`

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer! My question is actually about getting my scores through a query by order of the highest scores in order to display them on my scene! And I will try what you've given me to see how it works!